# Write more than 65535 rows in a csv file

Tags: java, csv

> [Update]Problem is different, nothing about csv file format. Question
>   would be "While using File Writer to write a csv file last few records
>   are missing.

In my java application i need to append more than 65535 rows in a `csv` file. but it only writes 65535 rows in a sheet. I haven't used any libraries. some final records missing. how to resolve this..........

```
public void writeSubmission(){
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter("res/sample.csv");
            writer.append("PhraseId");
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append("Sentiment");
            writer.append('\n');
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void readTestData(){
        String path="res/test.tsv"; 
        Calculation cal=new Calculation();
        int counter=0;
        try {
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line;
            writeSubmission();
            bReader.readLine();
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String datavalue[] = line.split("\t");
                writer.append(datavalue[0]);
                writer.append(',');

                try {
                    double value=cal.calculate(datavalue[2]);
                    System.out.println(value);
                    String val;
                    if(value<-0.4)
                    {
                        val="0";
                    }
                    else if(value>-0.4 && value<-0.1)
                    {
                        val="1";
                    }
                    else if(value>-0.1 && value<+0.1)
                    {
                        val="2";
                    }
                    else if(value>+0.1 && value<+0.40)
                    {
                        val="3";
                    }
                    else{
                        val="4";
                    }
                    counter++;
                    writer.append(val);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                writer.append('\n');

            }
            System.out.println(counter);
            bReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Code. We need more code.

Comment: how do you find out that there are only 65535 rows in the sheet? Have you tried a normal text editor and see how many lines are there?

Comment: Sounds like it might be being opened in an older version of Excel which has a row limitation

Comment: i used FileWriter to open the file and used loop to enter data for each entry what do you expect more

Comment: Has nothing to do with writing the file, but rather with whatever you're using to read it.

Comment: i.e: OpenOffice 4+ supports more lines than its previous versions..

Comment: Yup, @RussCam is right. Excel 2003 and earlier limits its sheets to 65535 rows. So that's probably it. Open the generated .csv with a newer version of Excel or other software.

Comment: in read part part i checked iterations using a count variable it's shows correct value

Comment: it is not possible to exception. only last part of my values missing

Comment: Is that a new question ?

Comment: no. they asked to code for read part.

Comment: So its working , right ?

Comment: nope. last 2000 records missing

Comment: You have a very strange way of testing. Aren't you opening the same file ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Excel, not about writing files in Java.

Comment: You are mistaken about it only writing 65535 rows, and you could easily have determined that for yourself by inspection instead of jumping to conclusions. -1

Comment: finally i found the answer. it is about java. i forgot flush the filewriter. fixed

Comment: I'm a little late to this party, but it's worth mentioning that even relatively recent versions of Apple's Numbers spreadsheet viewer have this same limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fixed the error.File Writer should be `flush` after used in the code push existing stream. OR should be `close` the writer it automatically `flush` and `close`

> The flush method flushes the output stream and forces any buffered
>   output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that
>   calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have
>   been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes
>   should immediately be written to their intended destination.

```
writer = new FileWriter("res/sample.csv");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: I think you will find that you can remove the `flush()` call and it will still work. The problem was that you were never calling `writer.close()`, which automatically performs the flush operation for you.

Comment: right i thought it. Bt confused in another close() call

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue is *probably* that the tool you're opening up the CSVs with on the other end doesn't want more than 65535 rows, not that Java's doing anything wrong.  It's a bug on the other end, not your Java code, almost certainly.  (`FileWriter` wouldn't care at all about 65535 lines, for example.)

If you're using Excel 2003, for example, you'd see this issue: [How to get around 64k row limit in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121871/how-to-get-around-64k-row-limit-in-excel)

Comment: To debug this, add an extra column to your CSV file with an integer that is incremented for each row.  Then look at the generated CSV file using tools like `head` (show first few lines), `tail` (show last few lines) and `wc` (count the lines).  If you have nothing better, the file size as reported by the operating system might be an indicator, too.